# setting ACLs for subfolders using Web Deploy package

Tags: visual-web-developer, msdeploy, web-deployment

I’m trying to build a Deployment Package in Visual Web Developer Express 2010 which sets the ACL for a subfolder of the deployed website. I used the following information http://leethams.wordpress.com/2010/06/12/modifying-directory-permissions-with-web-deployment/

This is my test:

Create a new blank ASP.NET Application (WebApplication2 in this example)

In advanced compilation options, change .NET Framework target version to 3.5

Create a new folder (Config in this example) and add any file inside the folder

Create a new file called WebApplication2.wpp.targets, with this content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- Extends the AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest action do also set ACLs -->
        <IncludeCustomACLs>TRUE</IncludeCustomACLs>
        <AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest Condition="'$(AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest)'==''">
            $(AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest);
            SetCustomACLs;
        </AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="SetCustomACLs" Condition="'$(IncludeCustomACLs)'=='TRUE'">
        <Message Text="Adding Custom ACls" />
        <ItemGroup>
            <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="setAcl" Condition="$(IncludeSetAclProviderOnDestination)">
                <setAclUser>anonymousAuthenticationUser</setAclUser>
                <path>$(_MSDeployDirPath_FullPath)</path>
                <setAclAccess>Read,Write</setAclAccess>
                <setAclResourceType>Directory</setAclResourceType>
                <AdditionalProviderSettings>setAclResourceType;setAclAccess</AdditionalProviderSettings>
            </MsDeploySourceManifest>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

I execute from the command line and everything works fine:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 Start executing msdeploy.exe
-------------------------------------------------------
 "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\\msdeploy.exe" -source:package='C:\T
emp\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\obj\Debug\Package\WebApplication2.zip' -dest
:auto,includeAcls='False' -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:
ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:"C:\Temp\WebApp
lication2\WebApplication2\obj\Debug\Package\WebApplication2.SetParameters.xml"

Info: Actualizando setAcl (Default Web Site/WebApplication2_deploy).
Info: Actualizando setAcl (Default Web Site/WebApplication2_deploy).
Info: Actualizando setAcl (Default Web Site/WebApplication2_deploy).
Número total de cambios: 3 (0 agregados, 0 eliminados, 3 actualizados, 0 parámet
ros cambiados, 0 bytes copiados)
```

Now, to set the permissions for the Config folder, I change the following line and rebuild the deployment package.

```
<path>$(_MSDeployDirPath_FullPath)/Config</path>
```

I get the following error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 Start executing msdeploy.exe
-------------------------------------------------------
 "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\\msdeploy.exe" -source:package='C:\T
emp\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\obj\Debug\Package\WebApplication2.zip' -dest
:auto,includeAcls='False' -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:
ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:"C:\Temp\WebApp
lication2\WebApplication2\obj\Debug\Package\WebApplication2.SetParameters.xml"

Info: Actualizando setAcl (Default Web Site/WebApplication2_deploy).
Info: Actualizando setAcl (Default Web Site/WebApplication2_deploy).
Info: Actualizando setAcl (C:\Temp\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\obj\Debug\Pac
kage\PackageTmp/Config).
Error: Se debe especificar un valor para 'setAclUser' cuando se usa el proveedor
 'setAcl' con una ruta de acceso física.
Recuento de errores: 1.
```

In English it says: “Error: a value for ‘setAclUser’ must be specified when using the ‘setAcl’ provider with a physical path". Notice the third setAcl was changed to the physical path where the deployment package is located.

I then tried to modify it this way:

```
<AdditionalProviderSettings>setAclUser;setAclResourceType;setAclAccess</AdditionalProviderSettings>
```

But the error remains.
If I execute the deployment package with the “/t” switch, it does not throw the error, although it still shows the physical path.
I can hardcode the IIS path and change the line like this:

```
<path>Default Web Site/WebApplication2_deploy/Config</path>
```

It works fine. However, I wouldn’t like to do that, since the installation path need to be parameterized.

Changing the path to a backslassh makes no difference:

```
<path>Default Web Site/WebApplication2_deploy\Config</path>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Web Deploy's setAcl provider be used on a sub-directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861990/can-web-deploys-setacl-provider-be-used-on-a-sub-directory)