# How to automatically set folder permissions when deploying to an EC2 instance?

Tags: visual-studio, iis, amazon-web-services

When deploying, I currently have to remote desktop into my EC2 instance and change permissions for a folder through the IIS Manager.

Is it possible to have these permissions set when deploying through Visual Studio with AWS' Republish to Stack?

Comment: You can change the permissions on a folder by using webdeploy setacl providers - check out this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861990/can-web-deploys-setacl-provider-be-used-on-a-sub-directory