# Asp.Net MVC - SecurityException: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. Inaccessible logs: Security

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, sensenet, aws-toolkit

So I'm deploying my website through AWS Elastic Beanstalk(with an AWS RDS instance attached to it) using the AWS Toolkit Extension in Visual Studio. My web app is using both the sensenet service and sensenet webpages component. The sensenet services is a mandatory component that must exist for other sensenet components to be used. The sensnet webpages component provides an admin GUI for the user and this is what gets displayed whenever someone visits the site.

My problem is this security exception that occurs every time I go to my website(This problem doesn't occur when run it through localhost).

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Security Exception

Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file. 

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 

[SecurityException: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security.]
   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.FindSourceRegistration(String source, String machineName, Boolean readOnly, Boolean wantToCreate) +441
   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(String source, String machineName, Boolean wantToCreate) +125
   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(String source) +23
   SenseNet.Diagnostics.SnEventLogger..ctor(String logName, String logSourceName) +71
   SenseNet.Configuration.<>c.<.ctor>b__153_0() in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\Storage\Configuration\Providers.cs:83
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +708
   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +184
   SenseNet.ContentRepository.RepositoryInstance.InitializeLogger() in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\ContentRepository\RepositoryInstance.cs:350
   SenseNet.ContentRepository.RepositoryInstance.DoStart() in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\ContentRepository\RepositoryInstance.cs:130
   SenseNet.ContentRepository.RepositoryInstance.Start(RepositoryStartSettings settings) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\ContentRepository\RepositoryInstance.cs:107
   SenseNet.ContentRepository.Repository.Start(RepositoryStartSettings settings) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\ContentRepository\Repository.cs:55
   SenseNet.Services.SenseNetGlobal.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e, HttpApplication application) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\Services\SenseNetGlobal.cs:156
   DERContentRepository.MvcApplication.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e, HttpApplication application) in Global.asax.cs:12
   SenseNet.Portal.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\Services\Global.cs:16

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3163.0
```

A couple of stackoverflow posts that I've read like these

[System.Security.SecurityException when writing to Event Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274018/system-security-securityexception-when-writing-to-event-log)

[The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. Inaccessible logs: Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389248/the-source-was-not-found-but-some-or-all-event-logs-could-not-be-searched-inac/28219359)

talked about running visual studio as administrator(this did not work) and
creating a registry key with the name of the application. The last approach I'm pretty sure it would work in development but not sure if it would work when deploying. Any ideas how to deal with this when deploying the website?

IIS Express 10

ASP.NET MVC v4.6.2

Windows Server 2016 v1.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the system starts it tries to initialize the logger component. In the default installation this is a simple event logger that tries to write events into the **Windows Event Log** - and if the appropriate log does not exist, it **tries to create it on-the-fly**. In some environments the application user does not have (Windows) permissions for this, which is normal.

You have multiple options:

- create the event log manually (see the *createeventlog* SnAdmin tool [here](https://community.sensenet.com/docs/snadmin-tools/))
- use a different logger that writes log entries somewhere else, not the Event log. For example there is the *SnFileSystemEventLogger* that writes entries to the file system. To configure the logger you may use the repository builder API in your MvcApplication:

```

```
public class MvcApplication : SenseNet.Portal.SenseNetGlobal
{
    protected override void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e, HttpApplication application)
    {
        ...
    }

    protected override void BuildRepository(IRepositoryBuilder repositoryBuilder)
    {
        repositoryBuilder.UseLogger(new SnFileSystemEventLogger());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help Miklos. I opted for the filesystem solution and it did get rid of that exception. Unfortunately, another exception pop up. Here is a link to it https://hastebin.com/nubowesaru.coffeescript Note in my inetpub folder there is no wwwroot folder. In the beginning of the stacktrace I see that calls InternalCreateDirectory which it probably creates the folder without the proper permissions and fails when it tries to access the folder(just my guess).

Comment: I see, so the other exception has to do with giving aws elasticbeanstalk file system write access. Fortunately, there is a stackoverflow post that relates to this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28621421/how-to-set-folder-permissions-in-elastic-beanstalk-using-yaml-file